# Thanks - A Former Moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some of you have probably noticed, I have been inactive here for a while. A new job plus a wonderful son have taken up more of my time, and I haven't had the bandwidth to keep up my participation here (I'm also no longer in half marathon shape). Due to my inactivity, Stack Exchange have asked me to step down or get back involved. Unfortunately, I can't do the latter.

On my way out, I'd like to thank the community. I appreciate being elected and thoroughly enjoyed helping this fledgling community as much as I could. I'm proud to have been a part of the growth of this great resource for cooks everywhere. You all helped me become a much better cook, and I appreciate that most of all.

I will continue to post the occasional question and answer, so you might see me around.

Thanks for being an important part of my life for the last few years.

Comment: I came to the site after your active time had mostly passed... but you leave a legacy.  Good luck and fair wind.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, yossarian, for all of the work you've put into building this community. Hope to continue seeing you around on occasion - best of luck to you!

I've gone ahead and removed your moderator access.